# About conditionals

Tags: tense, verbs

Is it ok to say?
*(about the past)* I wouldn't have understood this if it didn't have happened to me before.
*(about the imaginary present)* I wouldn't understand this if it didn't have happened to me before.

Comment: ... *if it **hadn't** happened to me before.* *DO* is required only if there is no other auxiliary present; in this case *HAVE* is employed as the perfect auxiliary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the formation of the past perfect tense in the conditional clause. Saying "It didn't have happened" is incorrect

The past perfect is "had + past participle". The negative is "had not +past participle".

> I wouldn't have understood this if it hadn't happened to me before.

Apart from that, your analysis is correct.